# I'm getting "no module named ad" error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I tried to import pocketsphinx and sphinx base but both of this shows error as "`no module name ad`" error I don't know what this "`ad`" is

code:

```
>>> import pocketsphinx

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import pocketsphinx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pocketsphinx\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from sphinxbase import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinxbase\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .ad import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinxbase\ad.py", line 35, in <module>
    _ad = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinxbase\ad.py", line 34, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_ad')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _ad
>>> import sphinxbase

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import sphinxbase
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinxbase\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .ad import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinxbase\ad.py", line 35, in <module>
    _ad = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinxbase\ad.py", line 34, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_ad')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _ad
```

Comment: yup i do always get error as insecure platform warning

Answer (score 1):

`sphinxbase` has [C based component](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/doc/sphinxbase/ad_8h.html) compiled into a file named `_ad.so`, that is what seems to be missing on your system.

You should try to reinstall that module and make sure there are no install warnings that might indicate the compilation did not work out.

Comment: and i am even unable to install sphinxbase i tried installing it using pip but it was unable to find it

Comment: i have installed sphinx and pocket sphinx but while installing sphinxbase it doesnt finds any version and when i searched for it in my python27 folder i did find it but i guess there as some files or folder missing and pip is not even recognising this sphinxbase folder

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug tracked at repo

https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python/issues/19

To fix it you have to rebuild the module or ask maintainer to upload proper version.

You can also use pocketsphinx official API and pyaudio, it will work fine without ad.